# Get particular set of lines when exception occurs using Logstash

Tags: cmd, logstash

I need to get only selected set of lines from logs when exception occurs.

**LOG I NEED TO PARSE:**

[2/24/16 11:31:35:276 SAST] 00000053 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getCustomerDashBoardCVAHistoricalDataRequestCount" on bean "BeanId(cva-admin-ear#vis-ejb-cva-4.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#CustomerDashboardServiceBean, null)". Exception data: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.AmbiguousEJBReferenceException: The short-form default binding 'za.co.sb.archiving.midtier.ejb.HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceRemote' is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface : [channel-frontendEAR#channel-biz-ejb-3-4.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean, nbol-rest-0_0_1-20150729_102930-10_war#nbol-rest-0.0.1-20150729.102930-10.war#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean]. Provide an interface specific binding or use the long-form default binding on lookup.]
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getRequestBusinessService(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:355)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:282)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getCustomerDashBoardHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:249)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.ejb.CustomerDashboardServiceBean.getCustomerDashBoardCVAHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardServiceBean.java:49)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.ejb.EJSLocal0SLCustomerDashboardServiceBean_7d8a7f63.getCustomerDashBoardCVAHistoricalDataRequestCount(EJSLocal0SLCustomerDashboardServiceBean_7d8a7f63.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice.ProcessServiceImpl.callService(ProcessServiceImpl.java:770)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice.ProcessServiceImpl.retrieveResultData(ProcessServiceImpl.java:1151)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice.ProcessServiceImpl.process(ProcessServiceImpl.java:248)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice.ProcessServiceBean.process(ProcessServiceBean.java:63)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice.EJSRemote0SLCustomerAdminProcessService_450d08b4.process(EJSRemote0SLCustomerAdminProcessService_450d08b4.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate$3.run(ClientDelegate.java:1266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke0(ClientDelegate.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate$ClientDelegate0.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1500)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.process(Unknown Source)
    at za.co.sb.midtier.processservice._ProcessService_Stub.process(_ProcessService_Stub.java)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.delegates.ModuleDelegate.processData(ModuleDelegate.java:48)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.CoreRouter.doGet(CoreRouter.java:231)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.CoreRouter.doPost(CoreRouter.java:459)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.CoreRouterFilter.doFilter(CoreRouterFilter.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.HTTPTokenFilter.doFilter(HTTPTokenFilter.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at za.co.sb.core.midtier.router.VerificationFilter.doFilter(VerificationFilter.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.AmbiguousEJBReferenceException: The short-form default binding 'za.co.sb.archiving.midtier.ejb.HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceRemote' is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface : [channel-frontendEAR#channel-biz-ejb-3-4.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean, nbol-rest-0_0_1-20150729_102930-10_war#nbol-rest-0.0.1-20150729.102930-10.war#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean]. Provide an interface specific binding or use the long-form default binding on lookup.]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1103)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookup(Helpers.java:796)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processBoundObjectForLookup(CNContextImpl.java:2876)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:3973)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1875)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getRequestBusinessService(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:352)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.AmbiguousEJBReferenceException: The short-form default binding 'za.co.sb.archiving.midtier.ejb.HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceRemote' is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface : [channel-frontendEAR#channel-biz-ejb-3-4.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean, nbol-rest-0_0_1-20150729_102930-10_war#nbol-rest-0.0.1-20150729.102930-10.war#HistoricalDataRequestBusinessServiceBean]. Provide an interface specific binding or use the long-form default binding on lookup.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.util.AmbiguousEJBRefObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(AmbiguousEJBRefObjectFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper$7.run(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.Utils.doWithRestoredPrivileges(Utils.java:157)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.getObjectInstanceUsingObjectFactoryBuilders(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:336)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.doGetObjectInstance(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:136)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.access$000(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:60)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper$1.run(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:98)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.Utils.doPrivileged(Utils.java:148)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.getObjectInstance(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:96)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.OSGiObjectFactoryBuilder.getObjectInstance(OSGiObjectFactoryBuilder.java:57)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:993)
    ... 72 more

**FILTER :**

```
filter{
        multiline {
                    pattern => "\[%{DATE}"
                    negate => true
                    what => "previous"
                  }
        grok {

              patterns_dir => "./patterns"
              match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* W %{GREEDYDATA:ErrorText} "]
              add_tag => "Warning Detected"
              remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
        }
        grok {
              match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* E %{GREEDYDATA:ErrorText}"]
              remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
              add_tag => "Error Detected"
        }
        grok {
              match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* I %{GREEDYDATA:ErrorText}"]
              remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
              add_tag => "Information Detected"
        }
        grok {
              match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* A %{GREEDYDATA:ErrorText}"]
              remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
              add_tag => "Application Detected"
        }
        grok{
            match => ["message", "%{JAVALOGMESSAGE:Error Class}"]
            remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"s
        }

        if [CLASS] =~ /BusinessExcep/ {
            mutate{
            add_tag => "Sikitan chinna payan"
            }
        } 


}
```

I am able to successfully process the logs when there is no exception, but when exception occurs filters aren't working properly. So inorder to get the required set of lines from the GREEDYDATA, what can i do. Is there any way i can get the exception cause from this ?

**Say only :**

at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getRequestBusinessService(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:355)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:282)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.pojo.CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.getCustomerDashBoardHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardVisServicePojo.java:249)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.ejb.CustomerDashboardServiceBean.getCustomerDashBoardCVAHistoricalDataRequestCount(CustomerDashboardServiceBean.java:49)
    at za.co.sb.channel.cva.customerdashboard.midtier.ejb.EJSLocal0SLCustomerDashboardServiceBean_7d8a7f63.getCustomerDashBoardCVAHistoricalDataRequestCount(EJSLocal0SLCustomerDashboardServiceBean_7d8a7f63.java)

The **aboVe is the main reason** for exception so can I get only these set of lines , droping the rest. Please help, couldn't find a way fro this. Exprets please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Make another grok pattern that matches "Caused by" and puts the stuff after it into a field.  It looks like there are some colons and brackets after the message that you might be able to key off.

Comment: But using another grok to match Caused by would eventually return as another json message but I want with previous log where i have captured CLASS, ZONE. is it any way we can process **ErrorText**(GREEDYDATA) to obtain the desired result ?

Comment: grok{} doesn't create messages; it parses a message and creates fields.  You have one long message, and can use multiple grok{} stanzas against it and create one document in elasticsearch.

Comment: I tried adding another grok:
if "Error Detected" in [tags]{
  grok{
   match => [ "message", ".+?; ((([a-zA-Z]+(\.|;|:))+) )+%{DATA:reason}(\n\t)((.+?Caused by: ((([a-zA-Z]+(\.|;|:))+) )+)%{DATA:reason}(\n\t))+"]
   add_tag => "working sooper"
  }
 }

Comment: If my doubts are very naive, very sorry!. Im new to this